# Specified WSDL is invalid!, Please select a validated *.wsdl/*.xml file on previous page shown on code generator

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I am using Axis2 codegen wizard to generate java class from wsdl.

My sample wsdl is below

```
<definitions name="HelloService"
   targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <message name="SayHelloRequest">
      <part name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
   </message>
   <message name="SayHelloResponse">
      <part name="greeting" type="xsd:string"/>
   </message>

   <portType name="Hello_PortType">
      <operation name="sayHello">
         <input message="tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
         <output message="tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
   <soap:binding style="rpc"
      transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
   <operation name="sayHello">
      <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello"/>
      <input>
         <soap:body
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
            use="encoded"/>
      </input>
      <output>
         <soap:body
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
            use="encoded"/>
      </output>
   </operation>
   </binding>

   <service name="Hello_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
      <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
         <soap:address
            location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/">
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

when I try to generate java through axis codegen it shows this error :

```
 Specified WSDL is invalid!, Please select a validated *.wsdl/*.xml file on previous page
```

How to validate my wsdl and what is wrong in my wsdl??

Comment: What happens if you put `http://www.examples.com/SayHello/HelloService?wsdl` in a web browser?

Comment: The problem is that your WSDL is not published anywhere. You can tell that by checking the `soap:address location` in the WSDL: `http://www.examples.com/SayHello/`, and adding the WSL name at the end with the `?wsdl` suffix. Check the real location of your WSDL to create your client.

Comment: I am new in webservices can you tell me how to get wsdl from this real url https://qa.tritononline.com/SSOServer/SSO.svc/RestService/Login then I can check axis tool from that wsdl???

Comment: Are you looking for this: `https://qa.tritononline.com/SSOServer/SSO.svc?wsdl`?

Comment: Yes, Now I got the wsdl but when I use this axiscode gen then I got a long code. I was seeking for a simple java beans code???

Comment: Because that wsdl is not the same as the WSDL in the code. Check home answer, it could fix your wsdl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your WSDL is that you do not close the `soap:address` tag. Replace

```
<soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/">
```

with

```
<soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello" />

                                                          ^
                                                          |
                                                          |
                                                      close tag
```

In general there is no need to publish the WSDL (install application on server) before generating the bindings.